# Testing grails controller throws java.NullPointerException

Tags: grails, groovy, spock

Next test is failing with `java.NullPointerException`

```
package org.ttm

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(ActorController)
class ActorControllerSpec extends Specification {
    StageDataService stageDataService = Mock()

    void setup() {
        controller.stageDataService = stageDataService
    }

    void 'index returns list of stages'() {
        Long id = 20

        when:
        controller.index(id)

        then:
        1 * stageDataService.getActors(id)
    }
}
```

What is wrong here?

This is the StackTrace:

```
'2014-04-10 22:22:31,471 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.support.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:57)
    at org.ttm.ActorControllerSpec.index returns list of stages(ActorControllerSpec.groovy:18)
'2014-04-10 22:22:31,472 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ttm.ActorControllerSpec.index returns list of stages(ActorControllerSpec.groovy:18)
'2014-04-10 22:22:31,473 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ttm.ActorControllerSpec.index returns list of stages(ActorControllerSpec.groovy:18)
'2014-04-10 22:22:31,473 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ttm.ActorControllerSpec.index returns list of stages(ActorControllerSpec.groovy:18)
'2014-04-10 22:22:31,474 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ttm.ActorControllerSpec.index returns list of stages(ActorControllerSpec.groovy:18)
'2014-04-10 22:22:31,474 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.ttm.ActorControllerSpec.index returns list of stages(ActorControllerSpec.groovy:18)
'2014-04-10 22:22:45,664 [main] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
```

Ok, I think that it can be the issue: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10538. My Controller is decorated with `grails.transaction.Transactional` tag. The workaround is to mock a class with `@Mock` tag. Holly Molly Bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a stack trace or anything, but `1 * StageDataService.getActors(id)` should definitely be `1 * stageDataService.getActors(id)`.

Comment: You beat me to it. :)

Comment: Yes, it's `stageDataService.getActors(id)`. I edited the question to put the StackTrace.